# pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: undefined field django_ct]

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to implement solr in django using haystack
but facing an error

Please Help

**search_indexes.py:**

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from search.models import Note


class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I did the following instructions:

1. python manage.py build_solr_schema
2. python manage.py rebuild_index

**The Error**

```
raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: 
undefined field django_ct]
```

Comment: If you found it out I am interested in the solution :)

Comment: i am sorry to inform that i never found a solution using haystack so I implemented solr without haystack

Comment: I have the same issue. Anybody found a solution ?